# Magento2: How to get content of file from remote sftp?

Tags: magento2, ftp, filesystem

I have one requirement in which i need to get zip file from remote sftp and read its data after extract it.

I see there is class `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp` which i can use like below.

```
   \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp $ftp
   ){
       $this->ftp = $ftp;
   }

   public function uploadFile(){
       $open = $this->ftp->open(
                   array(
                       'host' => 'hostname here',
                       'username' => 'username',
                       'password' => 'password'
                   )
               );
}
```

but how to retrieve files and extract it so i can copy to my server.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `read()` function defined in that same class:

```
/**
 * Read a file
 *
 * @param string $filename remote file name
 * @param string|null $destination local file name (optional)
 * @return mixed
 */
public function read($filename, $destination = null)
{
    if ($destination === null) {
        $destination = false;
    }
    return $this->_connection->get($filename, $destination);
}
```

And the code to copy a remote file to your local would be like:

```
$result = $this->ftp->read('/path/to/remote/filename', '/path/to/local/filename');
```

`$result` here is a boolean, which can be used to determine whether it's successful or not.

Comment: Hi, But file is compressed .gz file. I guess i need to extract before read it right?

Comment: you can extract it after it has been transferred to your local.